# Python append the data from multiple tables into the same list but some rows are missing

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, list

I tried to select from multiple table from a database and put the data into the same list but somehow when I printed the list out not all the records are in the list.

Below is the code I'm using

```
import pyodbc

ric = []
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes;DSN=x.x.x.x;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx')

cur1 = conn1.cursor()

sql1 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.Currency WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"
cur1.execute(sql1)
results = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results:
    ric.append(x[0])
    

sql2 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.HIBO WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"    
cur1.execute(sql2)
results2 = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results2:
    ric.append(x[0])

sql3 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.HK_Gold WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"    
cur1.execute(sql3)
results3 = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results3:
    ric.append(x[0])


sql4 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.US_Bond WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"    
cur1.execute(sql4)
results4 = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results4:
    ric.append(x[0])
    

sql5 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.Precious_metals WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"    
cur1.execute(sql5)
results5 = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results5:
    ric.append(x[0])
#ric = [x[0] for x in results5]    

sql6 = "SELECT nRic FROM STOCK.dbo.NorthBoundQuota WHERE nRic IS NOT NULL"    
cur1.execute(sql6)
results6 = cur1.fetchall()
for x in results6:
    ric.append(x[0])


    
print(ric)
cur1.close()
conn1.close()
```

The above code is what I've tried. FYI, it's just part of a websocket multi-thread program. And the tables have no relationship(no foreign key).

Comment: *"FYM, it's just part of a websocket..."* What does "FYM" mean? That's not an accronym I'm familiar with (and a Google doesn't give an appropriate result).

Comment: Who knows, can you see the pattern of what's missing and not? maybe print cuts off some items too

Comment: better loop through ric and print one item at a time to see

Comment: All the tables are in the same database - why not do a `union` or `union all` in a single query?

Comment: @Thom A It is a typo. It should be FYI

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried using UNION in a single query but some results are still missing. It seems like all queries are missing one result

Comment: @siggemannen I try for r in ric: print(r)    It's the same. All queries are missing one result

Comment: And that one missing record seem to be the last record in the tables. To clarify, I have 6 queries here. And all queries are missing the last record in their respective tables. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Using only `UNION` removes duplicate rows, so if you have duplicate `nRic` values that would explain the lesser row count. If you use `UNION ALL` instead you'll get all rows including the duplicates.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning There are no duplicate records tho. But finally I figure it out. Thank you for everyone's help.